# Why to check all conditions before proceeding?

Tags: java, android, if-statement

Hi I am a beginner to programming. I am trying to learn Android development from udacity.

```
Cursor cur = someFunction();
    if(cur != null){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), two.class);
    intent.setData(cur.getLong(2));
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Now in two class.

```
Intent intent = getActivity.getIntent();
if(intent != null){
    mString = intent.getDataString();
}

if(null != mString){
    mTextView.setText(mString);
}
```

I was just wondering why do we require so many `if`s in this code. The `if` in first piece of code is fine.

When the second activity was called from first activity. Why do we need to check if the intent is null? Since it is the only entry point to the second activity.
And why do we again need to check if the string is null before assigning it to `Text View`?

Comment: Well you technically don't need to check if they are `null` Just a safe check. Hardly downgrades performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you see it in some code, that doesn't mean it's required.

The check for null on the first condition isn't necessary.  The code here looks like it's being very paranoid that getIntent() might return null.

In the second condition, there is nothing that's telling the compiler that there is a guarantee that the return string will definitely not be null.  In fact, the documentation states that it may return null, so it's safe to always check.  You can put a null string into a TextView, but that isn't necessarily what's desired.  It's hard to tell without context.

Comment: `In the second condition, there is nothing that's telling the compiler that there is a guarantee that the return string will definitely not be null.`  But since we have set the data before starting the activity. Why do we again have to check after executing `getDataString()`?

Comment: You don't *have* to do anything.  It's a safety check.  It's impossible to tell if it's perfectly safe here because there is not enough context to see what all the cases might be.  Even if it is perfectly safe all the time, something might change in the future.

Comment: Because at some point in the future you may launch the activity and forget to set that data.  Its better to fail gracefully than to crash.  Its a concept called "defensive programming" and its a very important one to learn-  program assuming that something can go wrong, because it eventually will.

Answer (score 0):

Because if you don't check if something is null and try to invoke a method on it, it will cause a `NullPointerException`. That's why only after you've confirmed that the `Intent` is not null, you can call the method

```
intent.getDataString();
```

Comment: I understand it can give a `NullPointerException`. However what I wanted to know was why it would give `null` value to the intent since we started the activity for first activity and this is the only entry point to that activity. So  logically it should assign an `INTENT` to the `intent` variable. But I understood it later that due to some technical issue it might give `null` value to the `intent` variable. So that condition is just for being safe. Thanks for the answer. :)